# Checking whether an NSConcreteMutableData instance is empty

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdata, fbconnect

The result of FBConnect's `userInfo` is empty sometimes; the data type is `NSConcreteMutableData`, which `NSLog` shows as `<>`.

How do I check for empty or `nil` here? so Far I have tried `nil` and `[NSNull null]` but no success.

Answer (score 3):

`NSConcreteMutableData` is a private subclass of `NSMutableData`. For your purposes you might as well just check for any subclass of `NSData`.

```
if ([userInfo isKindOfClass:[NSData class]] && [(NSData*)userInfo length] == 0)
{
     // it's empty
}
```